# Dynamically choose compontent in Nuxt Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I would like to render the same component for all languages. The translation will be done inside the component. The url and component relationship should look like so:

```
pseudocode:
browserurl: "/blogpost_1"
nuxtcomponent: "blogpost_1"

browserurl: "/en/blogpost_1"
nuxtcomponent: "blogpost_1"

browserurl: "/randompage"
nuxtcomponent: "randompage"

browserurl: "/en/randompage"
nuxtcomponent: "randompage"
```

My approach was to do the following, unfortunately i cant find a way to access pathMatch.

```
router: {
   extendRoutes(routes, resolve){
   routes.push({
     path: 'en/*',
     component: resolve(__dirname, '/' + somehow.access.pathMatch )
})
}
```

}

Comment: `this.$route.params.pathMatch` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can resolve component dynamically. `component:` expects component instance or Promise. Once the promise resolves, result is cached. I can imagine solution using navigation guards and switching components "by hand" but that would require to import views by hand etc.

So your best bet is to rewrite paths generated by nuxt to include optional path segment (from `/about` to `/:lang(en|jp)?/about` so it accepts paths like `/en/about`) - your component then receives `lang` parameter which will be empty for `/about` otherwise it will contain language....

1. Define available translations in [meta](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1687#issuecomment-331870619)
2. Rewrite the paths of pages with translations

In your page:

```js
<script>
export default {
  meta: {
    translations: ['en', 'jp']
  }
}
</script>
```

In Nuxt config (pseudo - not tested)

```js
router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
        const routesWithTranslation = routes.filter(i => i.meta.translations && i.meta.translations.length > 0);

        routesWithTranslation.forEach(route => {
            const segment = `/:lang(${route.meta.translations.join("|")})?`
            route.path = segment + route.path           
        })
}
```

Comment: Nice hack but I would prefere a way of doing this with regex, rather than pushing hunderds of routes per language.

Comment: I made it better ;)

Comment: I just started looking into the path-to-regexp enginge! I think this is the most concise way to define all routes! Well done

Comment: Ideally i would have liked something like: try and catch, being able to define fallbacks. For instance, US fallback for UK, DE fallback for AT fallback for CH. etc.
But I guess this is the way its done. No reason to overcomplicate. This function is very flexible and extensible aswel..
+1 on the meta property.

Comment: Well that's something you can do in your code handling `lang` parameter inside the pages. Shouldn't be a router concern imho...