# How to make a start page in a dynamic directory?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

If I need start page with dynamic language URL like that:

> https://stackoverflow.com.**ru**./

What should I do?
Should I do a redirect from a static start page or other options are exist?
I need the right way.

Comment: It's not possible to do with Nuxt only. Nuxt doesn't control domain part of the url. Your web server does. What server are you using ?

Comment: Why is it not possible?
I can delete static index page and create nested route. 
After that I can create redirect(in nested route) to dynamic language page from it.

Comment: Your original question was how to redirect from `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/` to `https://stackoverflow.com/` and my comment was reaction to your original question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59392801/dynamically-choose-compontent-in-nuxt-router/59393401#59393401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 301 redirect by .htaccess
**ru** and **stackoverflow.com** are as examples

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ru\.stackoverflow\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ru\.stackoverflow\.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Place this .htaccess file in stackoverflow.com/ directory.

Comment: I need a solution basic on nuxt.js technology only.

Comment: Oh.. Ok. Sorry then